# Four column div with 3 regular columns and 1 rotated vertically

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make a **div** that contains **4** columns.

1. The first one should be **rotated vertically**. Text in it should be **centered vertically and horizontally**. It also should have a background and width 10%.
2. The rest columns (2, 3, 4) should have width 30%.

[image]
What is the best approach to do this?

P.S. Of course the div should be responsive and should look good at any resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, you will need to add min-height or height if the other divs with(30% width has too little content). in my case i added 300px;

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-center-all {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 10%;
  background: green;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.rotate {
   transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.container > div:not(.flex-center-all) {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex container">
  <div class="flex-center-all">
    <div class="rotate">rotate</div>
  </div>
  <div>text <br> txt</div>
  <div>text</div>
  <div>text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is good but what happens when the "rotated text" cannot fit in the div? I want size of the rotated div to be proportional to the length of the text in it. https://jsfiddle.net/ns23sh8s/